# Start service only on weekdays

Tags: android, service, xamarin, alarmmanager

I have the following code which starts a service every day at the specified time. Anyone know how to start it only from Monday to Friday?

```
    Calendar startTime = Calendar.GetInstance(Locale.Default);
    startTime.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, 10);
    startTime.Set(CalendarField.Minute, 00);
    startTime.Set(CalendarField.Second, 00);

    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService );
    Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(myService));

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetService(context, 0, i, 0);
    mgr.SetRepeating(AlarmType.Rtc , startTime.TimeInMillis , 24*60*60*1000 , pi);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use CalendarField.DayOfWeek. See :https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.Field.html#DAY_OF_WEEK. So you would want to do something like this:

```
startTime.Set(CalendarField.DayOfWeek, Calendar.Monday);
startTime.Set(CalendarField.DayOfWeek, Calendar.Tuesday);
startTime.Set(CalendarField.DayOfWeek, Calendar.Wednesday);
startTime.Set(CalendarField.DayOfWeek, Calendar.Thursday);
startTime.Set(CalendarField.DayOfWeek, Calendar.Friday);
```